# Rails 4 Boolean: Can't be set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean

I have a model with a boolean attribute "facturar" . I cannot set this attribute to true either through GUI or console. For some reason I can set it to false through console but not GUI. This happens if when I try to update any record of the model. Similar attribute "facturar_proveedor", also a boolean can be set to true or false in both GUI and console. What could cause this weird bug?

**Pertinent Code**

```
create_table "factura_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "factura_id"
    t.integer  "ordene_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.boolean  "facturar"
    t.integer  "iva",                limit: 8
    t.integer  "subtotal",           limit: 8
    t.boolean  "facturar_proveedor"
    t.integer  "subcuenta_puc_id"
  end
```

**Controller**

```
 class FacturaItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_factura_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /factura_items
  # GET /factura_items.json
  def index
    @search = FacturaItemSearch.new(params[:search])
    authorize FacturaItem
    @factura_items = @search.scope
    @factura_items = FacturaItem.all
  end
  # GET /factura_items/1
  # GET /factura_items/1.json                                                                                            
  def show
    @factura_items = FacturaItem.all
    authorize @factura_item
    @ordene = Ordene.all
    @medio = Medio.all
  end
  # GET /factura_items/new
  def new
    @factura_item =  FacturaItem.new  
    authorize @factura_item                                                                    
  end
  # GET /factura_items/1/edit
  def edit
    authorize @factura_item
  end
  # POST /factura_items
  # POST /factura_items.json
  def create
    @factura_item = FacturaItem.new(factura_item_params)
    authorize @factura_item
    @ordenes = Ordene.all
    @medio = Medio.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @factura_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @factura_item, notice: 'Factura item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @factura_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @factura_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /factura_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /factura_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      authorize @factura_item
      if @factura_item.update(factura_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @factura_item, notice: 'Item de factura asociado con factura.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @factura_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @factura_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /factura_items/1
  # DELETE /factura_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @factura_item.destroy
    authorize @factura_item
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to factura_items_url, notice: 'Factura item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_factura_item
      @factura_item = FacturaItem.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def factura_item_params
      params.require(:factura_item).permit(:factura_id, :ordene_id, :medio_id, :revisado, :fecha_orden, :medida, :unidad, :costo_unidad, :total, :facturar, :cantidad, :facturar_proveedor, :sin_iva, :subcuenta_puc_id)
    end
end
```

**Edit Form**

```
<% content_for :title do %>Factura Item<% end %>
<h3>Asignar Item a Factura</h3>
    <div class="form">
    <%= simple_form_for @factura_item do |form| %>
    <%= form.input :facturar, label: 'Facturar a Cliente' %>
    <%= form.input :facturar_proveedor, label: 'Facturar a Proveedor' %>
    <%= form.input :sin_iva %>
    <%= form.association :factura, :label_method => :id, include_blank: true, label: "Factura"  %>
    <%= form.button :submit, 'Guardar', class: 'submit' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<%= link_to 'Regresar', factura_items_path %>
```

**POST logs**

```
    Started GET "/factura_items/1/edit" for ::1 at 2015-10-26 22:10:57 -0500
Processing by FacturaItemsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  FacturaItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "factura_items".* FROM "factura_items" WHERE "factura_items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Factura Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "facturas".* FROM "facturas"
  Rendered factura_items/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (47.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 410ms (Views: 403.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)


Started PATCH "/factura_items/1" for ::1 at 2015-10-26 22:11:36 -0500
Processing by FacturaItemsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"r1IUDwfqd4U48wvc07dSUjCI2ki/iQfHEu7QMr9peNIaDPimLqCVX6HPjCV+pytGOwV4jW1FSSguFK71g+re0g==", "factura_item"=>{"facturar"=>"1", "facturar_proveedor"=>"0", "sin_iva"=>"0", "factura_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Guardar", "id"=>"1"}
  FacturaItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "factura_items".* FROM "factura_items" WHERE "factura_items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (1.1ms)  SELECT SUM("transaccions"."debito") FROM "transaccions"
  SQL (2.5ms)  INSERT INTO "transaccions" ("factura_item_id", "fecha", "debito", "subcuenta_puc_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["factura_item_id", 1], ["fecha", "2015-10-26"], ["debito", 1160000], ["subcuenta_puc_id", 128], ["created_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.359055"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.359055"]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "transaccions" ("factura_item_id", "fecha", "credito", "subcuenta_puc_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["factura_item_id", 1], ["fecha", "2015-10-26"], ["credito", 1000000], ["subcuenta_puc_id", 878], ["created_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.367100"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.367100"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "transaccions" ("factura_item_id", "fecha", "credito", "subcuenta_puc_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["factura_item_id", 1], ["fecha", "2015-10-26"], ["credito", 160000], ["subcuenta_puc_id", 880], ["created_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.371111"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.371111"]]
  Ordene Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "ordenes".* FROM "ordenes" WHERE "ordenes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Medio Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "medios".* FROM "medios" WHERE "medios"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/factura_items/1
Completed 302 Found in 117ms (ActiveRecord: 16.2ms)


Started GET "/factura_items/1" for ::1 at 2015-10-26 22:11:36 -0500
Processing by FacturaItemsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  FacturaItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "factura_items".* FROM "factura_items" WHERE "factura_items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered factura_items/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/factura_items/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_factura_items_show_html_erb__2824287575617260826_70230202524220'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/davefogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /Users/davefogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/davefogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/davefogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/726ca75c50ed7ed5/variables" for ::1 at 2015-10-26 22:11:36 -0500
  FacturaItem Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "factura_items".* FROM "factura_items"
  Ordene Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "ordenes".* FROM "ordenes"
  Medio Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "medios".* FROM "medio
```

**Model**

```
class FacturaItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :factura
  belongs_to :medio
  belongs_to :ordene
  belongs_to :subcuenta_puc
  has_many :incentivos


  before_save :calculate_total
  around_update :generate_transaccion_facturar_cliente, :if => :facturar?
  #running 1, 2 ,3 => before update,  4 => after_update OK
  before_update :generate_transaccion_facturar_proveedor, :if => :facturar_proveedor?
  after_update :generate_transaccion_incentivo_automatico, :if => :facturar?

  def calculate_total
    self.subtotal = (costo_unidad * cantidad) - (costo_unidad * descuento)
    self.iva = (subtotal * 0.16)
    self.total = subtotal + iva
  end

  def generate_transaccion_facturar_cliente
    #This callback creates a activo transaccions for the facturacion to a cliente.
    self.subcuenta_puc_id = 128 
    Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, debito: self.total, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
    # generate_transaccion_facturar_cliente_pasivo
    self.subcuenta_puc_id = 878
    Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, credito: self.subtotal, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
    #generate_transaccion_factura_cliente_iva
    self.subcuenta_puc_id = 880
    self.iva = 0  if self.sin_iva == true
    Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, credito: self.iva, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
  end

  def generate_transaccion_facturar_proveedor
    if cobro_proveedor == 'Facturacion'
    #This callback creates an activo deudores transaccion for the facturacion to a proveedor for a incentivo.
      self.subcuenta_puc_id = 129
      Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, debito: self.subtotal, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
      #generate_transaccion_factura_proveedor_iva
      self.subcuenta_puc_id = 742
      #if self.sin_iva == true
        #self.iva = 0  
      Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, credito: self.iva, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
      #Tgenerate_transaccion_facturar_proveedor_ingreso_operacional, his callback creates an ingreso operacional transaccion for the facturacion to a proveedor for a incentivo.
      self.subcuenta_puc_id = 1232
      Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, credito: self.subtotal, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
  end
end

  def generate_transaccion_incentivo_automatico
    if ordene.medio.tipo_de_volumen == 'Automatico'
      #This callback creates an activo incentivos por cruzar
      self.subcuenta_puc_id = 130
      Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, debito: self.ordene.incentivo, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
      #This callback creates an ingreso operacional cruce, :generate_transaccion_incentivo_automatico_ingreso_operacional 
      self.subcuenta_puc_id = 1233
      Transaccion.create!(factura_item_id: self.id, fecha: Time.now, credito: self.ordene.incentivo, subcuenta_puc_id: self.subcuenta_puc_id)
    end  
  end
end
```

SOLUTION: I have modified the callbacks in the model. I removed the around_update callback and placed its contents in after_update.

Comment: can you show us the logs for POST request that follows form submission?

Comment: I have updated the post with the logs required. I cannot find a POST request though. I only saw the PATCH. Help please.

Comment: Can you please post the full logs of PATCH. The logs you put is did not reach the part of saving the factura item.

Comment: @MeriAlvarado I have posted the additional logs. Please let me know if you need something else. Thank you

Comment: Can you also post the model code too please. Specifically looking for rails callbacks

Comment: @davefogo Kindly check my answer below. I think it is not actually saving since there is no `Update 'factura_items'...` in your logs.

Comment: Also, like what Gavin Miller said, your model code will also be helpful to debug your problem.

Comment: @MeriAlvarado I have updated the post with the model. I am not sure why there is no UPDATE entry ? This code used to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I have modified the callbacks in the model. I removed the around_update callback and placed its contents in after_update.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs for PATCH seems weird since it is not doing anything like:

`UPDATE "factura_items" SET "facturar" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "factura_items"."id" = $3`

And there are lots of logs that are not produced by your controller update action behavior like:

`(1.1ms)  SELECT SUM("transaccions"."debito") FROM "transaccions"
  SQL (2.5ms)  INSERT INTO "transaccions" ("factura_item_id", "fecha", "debito", "subcuenta_puc_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["factura_item_id", 1], ["fecha", "2015-10-26"], ["debito", 1160000], ["subcuenta_puc_id", 128], ["created_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.359055"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.359055"]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "transaccions" ("factura_item_id", "fecha", "credito", "subcuenta_puc_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["factura_item_id", 1], ["fecha", "2015-10-26"], ["credito", 1000000], ["subcuenta_puc_id", 878], ["created_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.367100"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.367100"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "transaccions" ("factura_item_id", "fecha", "credito", "subcuenta_puc_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["factura_item_id", 1], ["fecha", "2015-10-26"], ["credito", 160000], ["subcuenta_puc_id", 880], ["created_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.371111"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-27 03:11:36.371111"]]`

Comment: I have removed the callbacks for testing purposes and it works. Why would that be?

Comment: Reviewing active record callbacks might help : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html. I think some part of your code on around_update is not successful thus producing a rollback or the next process to stall.